# Get Json properties related to specific group or contxt

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to find a proper manner to build different json according to different context;

for example, given

```
@Data
public class Individual {

    private Address address;

    @myAnnotation(Perso.class)
    private String firstName;

    @myAnnotation(Perso.class)
    private String lastName;

    @myAnnotation(Finance.class)
    private String bankName;
}

@Data
public class Address {
    @myAnnotation(Perso.class)
    private String street;

    @myAnnotation(Perso.class)
    private String number;
}
```

I want to have a certain annotation that filters the properties for me smartly

for example, if I run my serializer in the context of "Perso" it gives me

```
{
       address : {
            street: "XXXX"
            number: "XXXX"
       }
        firstName: "XXXX"
        lastName: "XXXX"
}
```

but if I run it in the context of "Finance" it gives me only

```
 {
       bankName: "XXXX"
 }
```

I know that javax validation is using the same thins with annotations where it declares groups: for example @NotBlank(groups = {PersonalDataForm.class})

I want to have a light functionality that allows me to do the same!

Is there any library that allows me to do what I am aiming to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Jackson JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).